# TensorFlow Probability MixtureSameFamily layer code example: what are the parameters output from a connected dense layer?[python]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am looking at the example code from the [MixtureSameFamily layer documantion page](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/MixtureSameFamily). Specifically, I am interested in understanding what are the parameters output by the last Dense layer connected to the MixtureSameFamily layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tfd = tfp.distributions
tfpl = tfp.layers
tfk = tf.keras
tfkl = tf.keras.layers

n = 2000
t = tfd.Uniform(low=-np.pi, high=np.pi).sample([n, 1])
r = 2 * (1 - tf.cos(t))
x = r * tf.sin(t) + tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=0.1).sample([n, 1])
y = r * tf.cos(t) + tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=0.1).sample([n, 1])

event_shape = [1]
num_components = 5
params_size = tfpl.MixtureSameFamily.params_size(
    num_components,
    component_params_size=tfpl.IndependentNormal.params_size(event_shape))
md_model = tfk.Sequential([
  tfkl.Dense(12, activation='relu'),
  tfkl.Dense(params_size, activation=None),
  tfpl.MixtureSameFamily(num_components, tfpl.IndependentNormal(event_shape)),
])
```

In this case we have 15 values output from the last Dense layer. If I collect them in the following way for one fixed input sample indexed at 0:

```
extractor = tfk.Model(inputs=md_model.inputs,
                        outputs=[layer.output for layer in md_model.layers[:-1]])
features = extractor(x)
parameters = features[1][0]
```

what are the values found in the parameters array? I guess they should somehow relate to the mixture coefficients, location and scale of the 5 Normal distribution components constituting the mixture model. But how exactly? And in what order? I could not find this information anywhere. In other words, one thing that I would like to do is use them in a MixtureSameFamily **distribution** object, but I do not know how to assign them. I could do it only for num_components=1:

```
probs = [1] 
loc = [parameters[1]]
scale = [parameter[2]]

gm = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
    mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(probs=probs), 
    components_distribution=tfd.Normal(loc=loc, scale=scale))
```

But I could not find the proper pattern for num_components>1. Would you have any suggestion regarding how to do this?
If we find a solution, perhaps it could be added to the example/documentation page (I could try to contribute to it).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I have found the answer.
The code to assign the parameters to a distribution object should look like this:

```
params_reshape = tf.reshape(parameters[..., num_components:], tf.concat([tf.shape(parameters)[:-1], [num_components, -1]], axis=0))
loc_params, scale_params = tf.split(params_reshape, 2, axis=-1)
scale_params = tf.math.softplus(scale_params)
gm = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
    mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(logits=parameters[..., :num_components]), 
    components_distribution=tfd.Independent(tfd.Normal(loc=loc_params, scale=scale_params), reinterpreted_batch_ndims=tf.size(event_shape)))
```

I have found the answer by digging into the source code found in the github repository. Particularly, these two classes were useful: [MixtureSameFamily](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.13.0/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/distribution_layer.py#L1396-L1520) and [IndependentNormal](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.13.0/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/distribution_layer.py#L908-L1020).